# C# Fluently SQLLite InMemory System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

```
 public void Initialize()
    {
        sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
    }

    private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TestMetaData>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => configuration = cfg)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public ISession OpenSession()
    {
        ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        var export = new SchemaExport(configuration);
        export.Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, null);

        return session;
    }
```

This part is generating error **System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies on when are you applying the exportation of your schema on your exposed configuration. You should do it before you build your session factory.

Having created the sepparated method **OpenSession()** in which you are setting it makes me suspect you are applying it wrongly.

Thus, your session factory creation should be something like

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    //the session in which you might want to export your schema
    ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TestMetaData>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
         {
              //we set the configuration here, and execute it, 
              //before the session factory is built.
              var export = new SchemaExport(cfg);
              export.Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, null);
         })
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

¿Could you please give it a try and check if the problem is solved?

Comment: I know this is an old answer but my concern is. You are creating the sessionFactory inside the function CreateSessionFactory. How can you call sessionFactory.OpenSession() when it's not even created yet?